# Unable to parse atom feed using jQuery

Tags: jquery, atom-feed

I'm using jFeed to parse atom feed and trying to display the title. I had written success and error functions but it's not getting into either success or error function.

Below is my code. Please let me know what's going wrong with below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.jfeed.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

//read the atom feed

$.getFeed({
    type:"GET",
    url:"http://www.google.co.in/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly",
    success:function(feed)
    {
        alert(feed.title);
    },
    error:function(error)
    {
        alert(error);
    }

});


});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i see, your example is the same like the jfeeds. but the return data is normaly a list and not a single item, right? why you just dont set a breakpoint at "alert(feed.title") hover over the feed and look whats realy inside the object?

Answer (score 0):

$.getFeed doesn't take "type" and "error" parameters.

From the jfeed source:

```
jQuery.getFeed = function(options) {

options = jQuery.extend({

    url: null,
    data: null,
    success: null

}, options);

if(options.url) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: options.url,
        data: options.data,
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml) {
            var feed = new JFeed(xml);
            if(jQuery.isFunction(options.success)) options.success(feed);
        }
    });
}
```

so you are most likely getting an error.

Try sending a simple Ajax request to see what error you are getting.

Comment: now i had put only url and success but still it's not showing anything

Comment: you need to look for errors.. first just send $.ajax({ type: 'GET', url: yoururl, dataType: 'xml', error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus); });

Comment: I added .ajax() and it's going inside error function but still only error as message  . http://jsfiddle.net/sukumar/sWPkT/

Comment: you are trying to send a cross-domain request, those are not allowed for security reasons.